# SQL Server - getting info from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble creating a query which in my mind should be simple.

I have two tables (`tblReviews` and `tblRating`). Both these tables have a `venueId` and a `userId`.

I want to create a single query that will return the review and the rating using the same `venueId` and `userId`. is this possible or should I use two queries?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Rev.column_name, Rat.column_name
  FROM dbo.tblReview AS Rev
  FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.tblRating AS Rat
  ON Rev.VenueId = Rat.VenueId
  AND Rev.UserId = Rat.UserId;
```

If you want all for a specific user:

```
SELECT Rev.column_name, Rat.column_name
  FROM dbo.tblReview AS Rev
  FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.tblRating AS Rat
  ON Rev.VenueId = Rat.VenueId
  AND Rev.UserId = Rat.UserId
  WHERE (Rev.UserId = @UserId OR Rat.UserId = @UserId);
```

If you want all for a specific venue:

```
SELECT Rev.column_name, Rat.column_name
  FROM dbo.tblReview AS Rev
  FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.tblRating AS Rat
  ON Rev.VenueId = Rat.VenueId
  AND Rev.UserId = Rat.UserId
  WHERE (Rev.VenueId = @VenueId OR Rat.VenueId = @VenueId);
```

Comment: Also, what if there is more than one record in either table for a venueid/userid combination?

Comment: Right, in this simple case you'll get two rows - one side will have the same data in both rows.

Comment: There will only ever be one record in each table and I want to get results no matter if both tables have a result, both table don't have a result or just one of the tables has a result

Comment: What do you want returned if "both table don't have a result"?

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Join both tables using these fields;
2. ..or (SELECT first) UNION (SELECT second)

Comment: I tried both of these methods. The union didn't work (I think) because the two data types are not the same. The join didn't work as there is not allways going to be data in each table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblReviews AS rev INNER JOIN
     tblRating AS rat ON rev.venueid = rat.venueid AND rev.userid = rat.userid
```

This query returns the matching rows from each tables. You can use outer joins (LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN, also FULL OUTER JOIN) if you want all records from first, second, or both table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're asking this.
Try:

```
SELECT re.venueId, re.userId, re.review, ra.rating
FROM tblReviews re INNER JOIN tblRating ra
ON re.venueId = ra.venueId AND re.userId = ra.userId
```